# Wifi problem Acer Aspire A114-31-C3RS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, acer

I have a problem with my notebook. I am currently using **Ubuntu 19.04**.
I can connect to my wifi router but I can't see my other wifi extenders. With **Windows 10** I did not have this problem so it is not a problem of my wireless card. It would not be a problem normally but when I am too far from the router I lose the connection. Could it be a driver problem?
I don't know what type of wireless card I have because I don't know how to see that on Ubuntu and I can't start windows 10 anymore.
I am a newbie in Ubuntu so for now I can just give you these informations.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT** :

I typed

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

in the terminal and I got:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
  Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:08a6]
  Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
  Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Entered In terminal: `iw reg get; dmesg | grep ath`

Results:

```
global
country IT: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

[    5.653465] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/spice-vdagentd.service:8: PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagentd.pid → /run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagentd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
[    6.599357] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    6.902256] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 11ad:08a6
[    6.902260] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    6.902972] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 42e41877
[    6.973423] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 8aedfa4a
[    7.049244] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    7.075851] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.56 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    7.162592] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[    7.162596] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    7.162598] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    7.162599] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[    7.215966] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   10.809908] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   15.726278] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x817c
[   15.726279] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   15.726279] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   15.726280] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[   15.726282] ath: Country alpha2 being used: IT
[   15.726282] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[   15.726284] ath: regdomain 0x817c dynamically updated by country element
[ 1058.736277] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x817c
[ 1058.736278] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 1058.736279] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 1058.736280] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 1058.736281] ath: Country alpha2 being used: IT
[ 1058.736282] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 1058.736283] ath: regdomain 0x817c dynamically updated by country element
[ 5202.538198] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 5202.578807] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 4562 at drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/mac.c:5708 ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xe74/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5202.578811] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc arc4 snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl snd_compress ac97_bus intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core intel_pmc_ipc snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm i915 snd_seq_midi kvmgt snd_seq_midi_event uvcvideo vfio_mdev snd_rawmidi mdev vfio_iommu_type1 videobuf2_vmalloc aesni_intel videobuf2_memops vfio videobuf2_v4l2 aes_x86_64 ath10k_pci crypto_simd joydev snd_seq cryptd videobuf2_common btusb kvm glue_helper ath10k_core intel_cstate videodev btrtl intel_rapl_perf btbcm media btintel ath irqbypass input_leds bluetooth snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper mac80211 serio_raw
[ 5202.578960] RIP: 0010:ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xe74/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5202.579015]  ? ath10k_conf_tx+0x80/0x4a0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5202.579523] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 4562 at drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/mac.c:5746 ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xdca/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5202.579525] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc arc4 snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl snd_compress ac97_bus intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core intel_pmc_ipc snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm i915 snd_seq_midi kvmgt snd_seq_midi_event uvcvideo vfio_mdev snd_rawmidi mdev vfio_iommu_type1 videobuf2_vmalloc aesni_intel videobuf2_memops vfio videobuf2_v4l2 aes_x86_64 ath10k_pci crypto_simd joydev snd_seq cryptd videobuf2_common btusb kvm glue_helper ath10k_core intel_cstate videodev btrtl intel_rapl_perf btbcm media btintel ath irqbypass input_leds bluetooth snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper mac80211 serio_raw
[ 5202.579646] RIP: 0010:ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xdca/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5202.579695]  ? ath10k_conf_tx+0x80/0x4a0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5204.083325] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 5209.022097] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x817c
[ 5209.022100] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 5209.022101] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 5209.022104] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 5209.022106] ath: Country alpha2 being used: IT
[ 5209.022108] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 5209.022112] ath: regdomain 0x817c dynamically updated by country element
[ 5616.322073] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 5616.363121] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 4855 at drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/mac.c:5708 ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xe74/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5616.363125] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc arc4 snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl snd_compress ac97_bus intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core intel_pmc_ipc snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm i915 snd_seq_midi kvmgt snd_seq_midi_event uvcvideo vfio_mdev snd_rawmidi mdev vfio_iommu_type1 videobuf2_vmalloc aesni_intel videobuf2_memops vfio videobuf2_v4l2 aes_x86_64 ath10k_pci crypto_simd joydev snd_seq cryptd videobuf2_common btusb kvm glue_helper ath10k_core intel_cstate videodev btrtl intel_rapl_perf btbcm media btintel ath irqbypass input_leds bluetooth snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper mac80211 serio_raw
[ 5616.363283] RIP: 0010:ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xe74/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5616.363341]  ? ath10k_conf_tx+0x80/0x4a0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5616.363808] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 4855 at drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/mac.c:5746 ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xdca/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5616.363810] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc arc4 snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl snd_compress ac97_bus intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core intel_pmc_ipc snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm i915 snd_seq_midi kvmgt snd_seq_midi_event uvcvideo vfio_mdev snd_rawmidi mdev vfio_iommu_type1 videobuf2_vmalloc aesni_intel videobuf2_memops vfio videobuf2_v4l2 aes_x86_64 ath10k_pci crypto_simd joydev snd_seq cryptd videobuf2_common btusb kvm glue_helper ath10k_core intel_cstate videodev btrtl intel_rapl_perf btbcm media btintel ath irqbypass input_leds bluetooth snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper mac80211 serio_raw
[ 5616.363939] RIP: 0010:ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xdca/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5616.363991]  ? ath10k_conf_tx+0x80/0x4a0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5646.447982] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 5646.488990] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 4842 at drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/mac.c:5708 ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xe74/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5646.488993] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc arc4 snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl snd_compress ac97_bus intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core intel_pmc_ipc snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm i915 snd_seq_midi kvmgt snd_seq_midi_event uvcvideo vfio_mdev snd_rawmidi mdev vfio_iommu_type1 videobuf2_vmalloc aesni_intel videobuf2_memops vfio videobuf2_v4l2 aes_x86_64 ath10k_pci crypto_simd joydev snd_seq cryptd videobuf2_common btusb kvm glue_helper ath10k_core intel_cstate videodev btrtl intel_rapl_perf btbcm media btintel ath irqbypass input_leds bluetooth snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper mac80211 serio_raw
[ 5646.489116] RIP: 0010:ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xe74/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5646.489159]  ? ath10k_conf_tx+0x80/0x4a0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5646.489633] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 4842 at drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/mac.c:5746 ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xdca/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5646.489635] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc arc4 snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl snd_compress ac97_bus intel_telemetry_pltdrv intel_punit_ipc intel_telemetry_core intel_pmc_ipc snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hwdep ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm i915 snd_seq_midi kvmgt snd_seq_midi_event uvcvideo vfio_mdev snd_rawmidi mdev vfio_iommu_type1 videobuf2_vmalloc aesni_intel videobuf2_memops vfio videobuf2_v4l2 aes_x86_64 ath10k_pci crypto_simd joydev snd_seq cryptd videobuf2_common btusb kvm glue_helper ath10k_core intel_cstate videodev btrtl intel_rapl_perf btbcm media btintel ath irqbypass input_leds bluetooth snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper mac80211 serio_raw
[ 5646.489764] RIP: 0010:ath10k_bss_info_changed+0xdca/0xfb0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5646.489816]  ? ath10k_conf_tx+0x80/0x4a0 [ath10k_core]
[ 5656.811486] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x817c
[ 5656.811487] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 5656.811488] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 5656.811489] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[ 5656.811490] ath: Country alpha2 being used: IT
[ 5656.811491] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[ 5656.811493] ath: regdomain 0x817c dynamically updated by country element
```

Inserted

`iwconfig`

And I got:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0f1  no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TIM-29002755"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: A6:91:B1:BA:8C:0C   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:64   Missed beacon:0
```

Inserted

`iwlist wlp3s0 freq`

I got:

```
wlp3s0    31 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. 
This will identify your WiFi device.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the post

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `iw reg get; dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. My router is working on 5 Ghz on channel 48.
The problem is the wifi extender that is working on the 2.4 ghz band. It is connecting to the channel 13 of the router. I tried a reset of the extender  and I was able to see it as a connection and even configure it but when I finish the configuration, my pc does not recognize it anymore. I even forced the extender  on channel 11 without any improvement.

Comment: You're in Italy, yes? You've set the extenders in "extend/repeat" mode, yes? Not AP mode. Depending on where you got your extenders, they may not really recognize channels 12 & 13. The router may not really transmit on 12 & 13. Reset the extender and try and get both channels set to 1 or 6 or 11. Edit your question and show me the output of the two commands in my answer. Start comments to me with @heynnema, or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I am in Italy and yes the extender is not in AP mode. I Edited the question with the command you said me to write in the terminal.

Comment: As I suspected... your wi-fi doesn't say it supports channel 13... and your router might not either. Try re-configuring the extenders to connect to the router on channels 1-11, and then the extender network to use channels 1-11. As a side note, use the higher channels in the 5ghz side, as they work better than the lower channels (48).

Comment: @heynnema Do I have to change also the channel of my router? I am trying right now to change first the options of my wifi extender.

Comment: Yes, you may have to change the router from AUTO, to a static channel 1-11.

Comment: @heynnema I just solved the problem changing the channel to 1-11 from 13! thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your extenders may not be using a channel that your wireless card can see.

In `terminal`...

`iwconfig` # determine the name of your wireless device

`iwlist wlan0 freq` # change wlan0 to the name of your wireless device

Observe the available wireless channels in your wireless device.

For the 2.4ghz band you should see channels 1-11, and for the 5ghz band you should see something like channels 36~161, with some channels not showing.

Confirm that your wireless extenders are using one of these available channels. If the extender is set to AUTO, it might not be using a channel that's visable to your wireless device. You'll have to set the extender to use a specific channel.

**Update #1:**

The channels displayed/used may be slightly different in IT.

**Update #2:**

*I just solved the problem changing the channel to 1-11 from 13! thank you very much*